# How to add <b>..</b> within an anchor link?

Tags: html, cakephp, anchor

Hi i am using cakephp version- 2.5.5. I want to add `<b>Main Index</b>` within an anchor tag

I want to-

```
<a href="/2014/myshowcam/msc/user-chat-images/"><b>Main Index</b></a>
```

My Code-

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('b', 'Main Index'),'/user-chat-images/');?>
```

My output-

```
<a href="/2014/myshowcam/msc/user-chat-images/">&lt;b&gt;Main Index&lt;/b&gt;</a>
```

Please suggest me and let me know how to add `<b>...</b>` within a anchor tag in CakePHP format?

Comment: I didn't say anything about Google, and I'm for sure not a clairvoyant, I just came to a conclusion based on the fact that this has been asked many times already and that it is properly documented in the Cookbook. If you don't want people to tell you what's wrong, then don't ask for it. ps, none of the downvotes is from me. pps, who deleted my previous comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the escape option to false. Read the documenentation.

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('b', 'Main Index'),'/user-chat-images/', array('escape' => false));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always put the option `'escape'=>false` for all links,forms,text and all in Cakephp to just display the html code.